# Updating just one column value using LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, linq

Suppose I have the ID of a column in a table and I want to increment one of it's column values by 1. How should I go about this.

This is what I already have. 
Table has 3 properties, (id, category, value)

```
var col1= db.columns.Where(w => w.category.Equals("Cars"));
```

I want to increment the value in the table which has category "Cars" by 1. 
What is the LINQ Query for this.

A similar question may have been asked before but no answer I have seen seems satisfactory enough.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var col1= db.columns.Where(w => w.category.Equals("Cars"));
foreach (var item in col1)
{
    item.SPECIFIC_PROPERTY = "VALUE";
}

try
{
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   //Handle ex
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a `.ForEach` extension method (you would have to enumerate first), but Linq should be used to query, not to update values.

So use a `foreach`

```
foreach (var car in col1) {
  car.value +=1;
}

//some method to save changes
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply

1. create your query which will return what you want from the db using your where clause
2. Makes your changes in your code
3. Submit your changes

Here's an example in the MSDN about how to update row in the DB [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399339%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

this way works for me:

```
 var cols = dbContext.table_name.Where(w => w.columnName == parameterName);
            foreach(var item in cols)
            {
                item.last_updated_date = dtNow;
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this

```
db.columns
  .Where(w => w.category.Equals("Cars"))
  .Select(x => { c.Value += 1; return x; })
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Please explain what you have done and why. This is not clear.

Comment: Hello, maybe you could explain what is the `c.Value` exactly ?